# How can I use jQuery to access an element that's stored in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, forms

I am building an HTML form, and for one section of it, a cluster of HTML input fields inside of a div needs to be pushed to an array.  The div and all of the fields get unique ids/names when created - in particular, one of the inputs is a select.

All of this works fine - the fields are created and pushed to the array, everything id'd correctly, etc., but I can't seem to access the select element for a jQuery change function that is supposed to come later, after the fields have been created.  I tested out an inline Javascript "onchange = myFunction()" type thing and this was able to access the select element - I get why this works, but it's not going to be an acceptable solution... I really need to use a $("#id").change function.

How can I use jQuery to access a select element that's stored in an array?

```
 this['input_array' + siteName] = [];

 for (y = 0; y < numberFound; y++){
 this['input_array' + siteName].push('<div id="'+routeValue+''+siteName+'Details'+y+'" class="details">Species: <select id="'+siteName+'Species'+y+'" name="species['+y+']" data-speciesNumber="'+y+'">'+speciesList+'</select></div>);

     $("#"+siteName+"Species"+y+"").change(function(){
       species = this.value;
       speciesNumber = this.getAttribute("data-speciesNumber");
       siteSpeciesNumber = displayName + "" + species + "" + speciesNumber;
       document.getElementById(""+siteName+"compileField"+speciesNumber+"").value = siteSpeciesNumber;
       });

      };

      $("#"+routeValue+""+siteName+"Details").append(this['input_array' + siteName]);
```

Comment: *I'll try to parse this as simply as I can as my code is a bit of a mess and would rather not have to bog anyone down with trying to slog through it...* Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve It's impossible to figure out what the problem is if you don't show at least minimal code and intent.

Comment: instead of `$("#id").change`; go for `$(document).on("change", "#id", function(){ ... your code...});`

Comment: Unsure what you are asking. Are you creating the select from an array, and then trying to access it?

Comment: vijayP, that's it, thank you.  To clarify: divs containing groups of input elements are being pushed to an array in a for loop; the contents of the array are then being appended to the form.  One of the elements in those pushed divs is a select, and I needed a change event attached to that select element.  Even though each select element has a unique id, the common $("#id").change handler isn't able to access that element.  Replacing it with vijayP's syntax worked.  vijay - can you explain that answer, please?

Comment: Oh my fault, my original wording was unclear - I neglected to mention that there was a select in the pushed divs... sorry everyone.  Also, will add a little code shortly so hopefully someone else may benefit.

Comment: @skwidbreth the `$("#id").change` code doesn't work because jQuery ($) looks in the DOM to find the `$("#id")` element which hasn't been appended yet. When it doesn't find it (because it hasn't been appended yet), it has nothing to attach the handler to. `$(document).on` attaches the handler to the document then passes $("id") in as a parameter, basically if there is a change event that bubbles up to the document, that came from $("#id") then run this function. Since the document element is always there, it attaches the handler just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not that the select is inside an array, it's that it is not yet attached to the DOM.

Try attaching the event handler as part of the element. Now when jQuery inserts the element into the document, the event binding is registered.

```
function $newSelect(y) {
    return $('<select />', {
        html: speciesList,
        id: siteName + 'Species' + y,
        name: 'species[' + y + ']',
        data: {
            speciesNumber: y
        },
        on: {
            change: function(){
                species = this.value;
                speciesNumber = this.getAttribute("data-speciesNumber");
                siteSpeciesNumber = displayName + "" + species + "" + speciesNumber;
                document.getElementById(""+siteName+"compileField"+speciesNumber+"").value = siteSpeciesNumber;
            }
        }
    }
}
function $newField (idNum) {
    return $("<div id="'+routeValue+''+siteName+'Details'+y+'" class="details"></div>", {
        html: $newSelect(idNum)
    });
}
this['input_array' + siteName] = [];

for (y = 0; y < numberFound; y++){
    this['input_array' + siteName].push($newField(y));
};

  $("#"+routeValue+""+siteName+"Details").append(this['input_array' + siteName]);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could attach your event handler to the document instead of the element.

Comment: That is fantastic, thank you.  vijayP's comment above does work, but this is the better answer for my situation, and far more comprehensive in general.  I appreciate the explanation, too.